# NetBeans: How to retrieve the build results of a project

Tags: netbeans-platform

My plugin is able to build a project listed in the Projects window and wondering how to retrieve the results of the build programmatically (i.e. the message "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" or the errors - as listed in the Output window)

Answer (score 0):

In the right bottom edge there are information about NetBeans updates. Left to it, there's the tasks running (building, running application etc). Click on it, right click the process you want and select Show Output.

Comment: Sorry, I missed adding the word 'programmatically'.